# How to backup drivers from a 5.1 ESXi install?

Tags: vmware-esxi, drivers

I have a running system with ESXi 5.1 using specific drivers for two network cards.
I can't remember how I found them, so I'd like to make a backup of these drivers for a new ESXi 5.5 install.

It this possible?

Comment: Did you put them in an `oem.tgz` on the ESXi boot volume, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You should install new drivers for your ESXi 5.5 setup, or check to make sure if the drivers are included in the new distribution. Do you know the specific makes/models of the network cards in use now?

Comment: My network cards are two D-Link PCI DGE-528T

Comment: @mimipc Oh, that [D-Link DGE-528T card](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/business-solutions/switching/network-and-switch-accessories/nic-cards-and-media-converters/dge-528t-dge-528t-copper-gigabit-pci-card-for-pc) is totally a desktop adapter. It's not supported or on VMware's HCL at all. I don't know if I would upgrade to 5.5 with that hardware.

Comment: It's not a production server, that's why it's not server hardware. I use this server for test purpose only. I also have a Intel PRO/1000 GT Desktop card. Would this one be better?

Comment: @mimipc The Intel card will work and is definitely supported for ESXi.

Comment: Okay, thanks :) I couldn't find it in the "Compatibility Guide".

Comment: Regarding my first question, is there a directory from which we can copy the drivers if we want a new fresh install of the same version of ESXi?

Comment: @mimipc Not sure. I wouldn't invest time in it. I'd use a supported adapter.